# How to fix errors with multiple instances of XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Recently I tried to use XmlHttpRequest for a project that I made
The code works like that

1. A user send informations that can be modified over time every 0.1 seconds
2. This informations are send to a php file which will modified a file text
3. The rest of the php resend all of the text file

Here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];

$texte = file_get_contents('pos.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$tab = explode(".", $texte);
$key = array_search($pseudo, $tab);
$tab[$key + 1] = $x;
$tab[$key + 2] = $y;
$texte = implode(".", $tab);

file_put_contents('pos.txt', $texte, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo $texte;
?>
```

And the text file looks like this :

```
AAA.0.0.BBB.0.0.CCC.0.0
```

If only one user use the site, the code works perfectly but if there are two users, after a moment, the text file looks like this :

```
.0.0
```

If anyone has a clue of what is the problem, please send me a response and thanks for reading this.

Comment: Don't use a file, use the DB.  If this data is to be shared between users you have a Race condition, where 2 processes access the data at the same time.  Process A & B bull pull same file data.  Process A does an update, then Process B uses old data (Without A's change) to do it's update.   AKA concurrency error.

Comment: You can try using `file_put_contents('pos.txt', $texte, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH|LOCK_EX);` Which will maybe prevent access to the file by multiple processes. But it may not solve all your problems. `LOCK_EX` is an exclusive file lock. There is still the chance between `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` for someone to read stale data. You can use`flock($f)` and `fopen()` etc (file handles). which would eliminate some more of that by locking the file before reading it.